# Excel-like filter for HTML tables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the code below which filters the values within HTML table based on selected values from a dropdown. It's supposed to work pretty much like the filters in Excel.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table th").click(function() {
    showFilterOption(this);
  });
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject) {
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");

  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")) {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }

  $(".filter").hide();

  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;
  filterGrid.append(
    '<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" style="width: 10% !important" checked>All</div>'
  );

  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tr");
  var values = [];

  $rows.each(function(ind, ele) {
    if (ind > 0) {
      var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
      if (!values.includes(currentTd.innerHTML)) {
        values.push(currentTd.innerHTML);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("grid-item");
        var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? "checked" : "";
        if ($(ele).is(":hidden")) {
          allSelected = false;
        }
        div.innerHTML =
          '<br><input type="checkbox" ' + str + " >" + currentTd.innerHTML;
        filterGrid.append(div);
        arrayMap[index] = ele;
        index++;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!allSelected) {
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }

  filterGrid.append(
    '<div style="text-align: center"><input id="close" type="button" value="Close" style="width: 40%"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok" style="width: 40%"/></div>'
  );
  filterGrid.show();

  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");

  $closeBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $okBtn.click(function() {
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind, ele) {
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")) {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      } else {
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });

  $checkElems.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $gridItems.click(function(event) {
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked", !$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });

  $all.change(function() {
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked", chked);
  });

  filterGrid.click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  return filterGrid;
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <tr>
    <th index=0>Email
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=1>Name
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=2>Level
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=3>Location
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 2</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
```

Currently, it shows the unique values of the table in the dropdown, but only filters out one of those values from the table. Any help would be highly appreciated regarding how I could make it filter all the matching values from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use a ready-made, drop down table filter, `ddtf.js`.

```js
(function($) {

$.fn.ddTableFilter = function(options) {
  options = $.extend(true, $.fn.ddTableFilter.defaultOptions, options);

  return this.each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('ddtf-processed')) {
      refreshFilters(this);
      return;
    }
    var table = $(this);
    var start = new Date();

    $('th:visible', table).each(function(index) {
      if($(this).hasClass('skip-filter')) return;
      var selectbox = $('<select class="form-control">');
      var values = [];
      var opts = [];
      selectbox.append('<option value="--all--">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');

      var col = $('tr:not(.skip-filter) td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')', table).each(function() {
        var cellVal = options.valueCallback.apply(this);
        if(cellVal.length == 0) {
          cellVal = '--empty--';
        }
        $(this).attr('ddtf-value', cellVal);

        if($.inArray(cellVal, values) === -1) {
          var cellText = options.textCallback.apply(this);
          if(cellText.length == 0) {cellText = options.emptyText;}
          values.push(cellVal);
          opts.push({val:cellVal, text:cellText});
        }
      });
      if(opts.length < options.minOptions){
        return;
      }
      if(options.sortOpt) {
        opts.sort(options.sortOptCallback);
      }
      $.each(opts, function() {
        $(selectbox).append('<option value="' + this.val + '">' + this.text + '</option>')
      });

      $(this).wrapInner('<div style="display:none">');
      $(this).append(selectbox);

      selectbox.bind('change', {column:col}, function(event) {
        var changeStart = new Date();
        var value = $(this).val();

        event.data.column.each(function() {
          if($(this).attr('ddtf-value') === value || value == '--all--') {
            $(this).removeClass('ddtf-filtered');
          }
          else {
            $(this).addClass('ddtf-filtered');
          }
        });
        var changeStop = new Date();
        if(options.debug) {
          console.log('Search: ' + (changeStop.getTime() - changeStart.getTime()) + 'ms');
        }
        refreshFilters(table);

      });
      table.addClass('ddtf-processed');
      if($.isFunction(options.afterBuild)) {
        options.afterBuild.apply(table);
      }
    });

    function refreshFilters(table) {
      var refreshStart = new Date();
      $('tr', table).each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        if($('td.ddtf-filtered', row).length > 0) {
          options.transition.hide.apply(row, options.transition.options);
        }
        else {
          options.transition.show.apply(row, options.transition.options);
        }
      });

      if($.isFunction(options.afterFilter)) {
        options.afterFilter.apply(table);
      }

      if(options.debug) {
        var refreshEnd = new Date();
        console.log('Refresh: ' + (refreshEnd.getTime() - refreshStart.getTime()) + 'ms');
      }
    }

    if(options.debug) {
      var stop = new Date();
      console.log('Build: ' + (stop.getTime() - start.getTime()) + 'ms');
    }
  });
};

$.fn.ddTableFilter.defaultOptions = {
  valueCallback:function() {
    return encodeURIComponent($.trim($(this).text()));
  },
  textCallback:function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text());
  },
  sortOptCallback: function(a, b) {
    return a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase();
  },
  afterFilter: null,
  afterBuild: null,
  transition: {
    hide:$.fn.hide,
    show:$.fn.show,
    options: []
  },
  emptyText:'--Empty--',
  sortOpt:true,
  debug:false,
  minOptions:2
}

})(jQuery);

$('table').ddTableFilter();
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

th,
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #1f2d54;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 45px;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30vh;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1f2d54;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.filter input {
  margin: 5px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='padding: 8px;'>
  <tr>
    <th index=0>Email
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=1>Name
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=2>Level
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
    <th index=3>Location
      <div class="filter"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 2</td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 3</td>
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
  </tr>
```